# Releasing a fork of a dormant project

Tags: forking, release

I'm working on an open source project ([Zscript](https://github.com/susanw1/zscript)), and it is dependent on a (Apache 2 licensed) build plug-in ([Maven NAR](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin)).

I have submitted some bug-fixes we needed to the plug-in's repo which have been accepted, but it's been a few years since there was a release, and my request for release status to their mailing list has had no response. In fact, the plug-in project essentially achieved most of its goals and the maintainers have drifted away.

I'm just setting up a GitHub CI build, and of course the CI build won't work without an updated plug-in release, and right now we build from a local master snapshot against the time when our changes are released. So I'm musing over my options:

1. I could offer to take over the plug-in project! But I'm not doing that - I don't have anywhere close to the bandwidth at this time. Maybe I'd kinda like to, one day.
2. Quietly absorb the plug-in code into our own codebase, and just copy the code in, give it a different disambiguating name.
3. Create a fork, give it a new module name and create my own release to a public repo.
4. Something else...

(For the avoidance of doubt, none of these options would involve changing the license or copyright attributions. We're totally happy to retain the legal rights and intent of the nice people who built the thing - we'd put a very clear statement to that effect. Zscript is generally MIT licensed, but we'd make it clear that that didn't extend to the NAR bit, if we do option#2. Plus, I'll carry on trying to establish comms.)

We can't be the first people to encounter this situation. What do other projects do? Are there any common guidelines, pros and cons, prior examples, anything we *shouldn't* do?

(To be clear, I know how to do this stuff technically. I'm just unsure of the approach.)

Comment: I hit "Post", and then all these useful existing questions finally start appearing, with useful answers. Is mine a dupe of https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/rules-guidelines-about-forking-a-project-vs-creating-a-new-one? Or this one? https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/whats-the-right-way-to-ask-if-a-github-project-is-maintained? Could be!

Comment: It's good that you found them!  Do they answer your question, or does anything remain unanswered (and if so, what)?

Comment: @MadHatter I think this one covers my options: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1942/18242 - more or less captures my opts #2,#3 above, which are the actual practical ones, and it doesn't suggest anything unexpected. I guess it might be nice if anyone had any cautionary tales, but as it is I think I'm good. As usual, formulating the question clarified the situation for me, I'll do #2 right now, and move to #3 down the line, esp if it remain dormant, and Zscript will need splitting up anyway!

Comment: Lovely stuff!  I have closed this question as a duplicate, but if it turns out clarification or further investigation is required, feel free to come back and ask a new question.  Linking to this one for context would probably be helpful if you did.  Hope that's all OK.

Comment: @MadHatter Perfectly good, thanks! Actually, I could add an edit in a little while to note how things went, would that be useful?

Comment: It doesn't really fit the structure of a Q&A board, but it's your question, and you should feel free to do that if you want to.  Perhaps instead of editing this question, you could consider adding an answer to the linked duplicate, letting people know you faced that scenario, how you addressed it, and how that worked out?

Comment: @MadHatter Yep, that sounds fine, I'll do that. Thanks again!